# jmeter tool for how many users can the system handle

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

how to know in Jmeter ( number of user the system can handle , number of user the system will crash)

okay this is the test I had

Min: The shortest time taken by a sample for specific label. If we look at Min value for Label 1 then, out of 75 samples shortest response time one of the sample had was 386 milliseconds.

Max: The longest time taken by a sample for specific label. If we look at Max value for Label 1 then, out of 75 samples longest response time one of the sample had was 134529 milliseconds.

How do I use this to calculate how many users the system can handle ?

Comment: A load testing tool is not going to tell you how much users the system can handle. It will tell you how fast a user is getting the content when the number of user is increasing. From there you should be able to figure out the maximum number of users for an acceptable response time.

Comment: okay this is the test I had Min: The shortest time taken by a sample for specific label. If we look at Min value for Label 1 then, out of 75 samples shortest response time one of the sample had was 386 milliseconds.
Max: The longest time taken by a sample for specific label. If we look at Max value for Label 1 then, out of 75 samples longest response time one of the sample had was 134529 milliseconds.                            how to calculate how many users the system can handle ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to define what does **"system can handle"** mean. Your system should have reliability requirements like these ones:

- Whatever resource is requested by a client the response should be returned not later than in 500 milliseconds.
- The system has to support 5000 user sessions at once
- The system has to support 1500 submit requests at once
- etc.

Once you have the requirements you're starting design your tests which account all the requirements from their "positive" and "negative" sides. You have to convert the requirements to the metrics which you'll be using for measuring the level of requirements compliance.

Having those test cases and metrics you are now free to code your tests in JMeter tool.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to starting scripting you should collect [non-functional requirements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement) which ideally should contain the anticipated number of your system users and maximum response time.

Looking into `134529` response time it doesn't seem acceptable as users will not wait for > 2 minutes for the page to load so I would rather suggest looking into i.e. [95% Percentile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) to identify what was the response time for 95% of requests.

With regards to determining maximum number of users:

1. Start with 1 virtual user
2. **Gradually** increase the number of users until response time start exceeding acceptable thresholds or errors start occurring, whatever comes the first.
3. When you identify the [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html) you will need to analyze the results to find the [bottleneck](https://qafoo.com/blog/082_common_bottlenecks_in_performance_tests.html)

See [8 Tips to Decide the Number of Concurrent Users for Your Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/8-tips-decide-number-concurrent-users-your-test) for recommendations on defining proper amount of virtual users and configuring the workload.